# Laravel migrate not working

Tags: database, laravel, migrate

I have a problem with my new laravel project.
Just after I create it, I try to make the migration with "php artisan migrate:install" but nothing happens ! Same with "migrate", "migrate:status" etc...

My terminal shows no error, nothing !
The connexion with the database is ok, when I change it with bad information, I got an error message.

I'm on mac and using MAMP.

here is my .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8888
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Also, as I am on MAMP, I use this:

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

But it is still not working ! and It used to work on my old projects...

Comment: Does your `test.migrations` table exist? Is there anything in it?

Comment: Also, does `storage/logs/laravel.log` show anything?

Comment: Thx for the help.
Nothing in the log, no error...
In my database migrations, I only have the user and password_reset Migrations... Where is the test.migrations ?

Comment: OK, how about the `test.migrations` table?

Comment: I don't have any "migrations" table in my database, Laravel wont create it.

Comment: There is probably a syntax error somewhere in your migrations. Can you share them with us ?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing change here, only the 2 basic migrations :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the migrations table does not exist, Laravel cannot reach the database.  Must be something in your connection.

Double checking the config you have shown:

```
DB_PORT=8888
```

In MAMP, that's the port Apache runs on, not MySQL.  [According to the docs](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Preferences/Ports/), MAMP runs MySQL on 8889, unless you have changed it.

Comment: So yes... Indeed.. Port 8889 and not 8888... OMG, so much time on this basic error.. Thx